# Problems with sql syntax on different servers

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, syntax, mariadb

I've made a NodeJS script that inserts data into a MariaDB database. I tested this first on my local PC and XAMPP. Everything was fine. Then I uploaded everything to my server. Now the Script is crashing every time when I try to execute a query. There is always the same error which says:

> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check th
> e manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
> syntax to     use near 'Where not exists(select * from discord where
> ID = '372444687497297920    '); SELECT ' at line 1

This is how the query is made:

```
var sql = "insert into discord (ID) Select ? Where not exists(select * from discord where ID = ?); UPDATE discord Set Money = ? WHERE ID = ?";
    var inserts = [id, id, amout, id];
    sql = mysql.format(sql, inserts);
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
```

Here are some additional information about the servers:

XAMPP-Server:

> Server-Typ: MariaDB
> Server-Version: 10.4.11-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
> Protokoll-Version: 10

"Real-Server"

> Server-Typ: MariaDB
> Server-Version: 10.3.22-MariaDB-0+deb10u1 - Debian 10
> Protokoll-Version: 10

Comment: Perhaps we can just start over. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to insert data into a row. But first I want to check if this row already was created. If not I want to create the row first.

Comment: What if someone else creates the row *while* you're checking?

Comment: I don't think that's a case to think about because there is only one user connected whit the database who is my skrip.

Comment: Show us the sql after substituting for the "?".  The problem seems to be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. The solution to this problem is quite simple. Just Upgrade your database to a higher version.